# Database Architecture for this scenario

Tags: architecture, database-design

Well, this architectural issue has been wandering in my mind for a while. Suppose the following scenario:
I have a `Licenses` table. Conceptually, each license can be limited to (License Types):

- Type 1: Number of tries. (e.g. allowing to run 7 times)
- Type 2: Trial (Time-limited).
- Type 3: Full
- ...

So, each license should store some custom value. (Type 1: Integer, Type 2: DateTime, Type 3: null)

What's the best architecture for this scenario?

- If I decide to put all the licenses in one table, I have at least 1 unused column for every row (EndDate would be null for Type 1, TryTimes would be null for EndDate and both would be null for Type 3):
  `LicenseID---LicenseType---CustomerID---EndDate---TryTimes`
  On the other hand, I'd like my design to be as flexible as possible (Maybe more license types in the future?)
- Another possible solution would be using some metadata-like approach:
  `LicenseID---LicenseDefinition---CustomerID---`
  Where LicenseDefinition contains information about the type and limit of the license and is parsed on the code side.

Which one do you suggest to be more conventional? Do you suggest any other way to implement it?

**UPDATE:**
Just found out about `Sparse` columns is SQL Server. Sounds very promising...

Comment: What about storing the data in a varchar field and having an extra column that specifies the type.  You'd need to do some conversion in your code, but that should be pretty easy

Comment: @Andrew: pretty close to my second solution. Why haven't you sent it as an answer? My preferred one so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head (I haven't implemented anything like this yet), I might do something like this:

Create database tables for `Customer` and `License`. Within `Customer`, along with all of the other generic customer information I would add a column for `licenseType`, which would `reference` the `License` table.

`License` would store the `licenseId` as well as any relevant meta data. **This would not include license-specific rules.**

On the code side, I would create a `LicenseFactory` class which would create an instance of a license interface (`ILicense`). `ILicense` might look something like this (in PHP):

```
interface ILicense
{
    public isValid($customer);
}
```

Then, I would have license-specific implementations:

```
class TrialLicense implements ILicense
{
    public isValid($customer)
    {
        // business logic for this specific license type here
    }
}
```

The factory class would look something like:

```
class LicenseFactory
{
    public static function getInstance($type)
    {
        switch($type)
        {
            case 0:
                return new TrialLicense();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

So now, my application code might look something like this:

```
public function isLicenseValid($customer)
{
    return LicenseFactory::getLicense($customer->licenseType)->isValid($customer);
}
```

None of this has been tested and are just my (rather long winded) initial thoughts. Hope it helps a little though (even though your app may not be php driven :))

**Edit:** 
Forgot to mention - the power in this approach is the extensibility. Any time you want to add a new license type, you'd simply add a new row to the `License` table and a new `ILicense` implementation with whatever business rules are required.

Comment: Very interesting Demian. The only limitation I can see is that customers cannot have more than 1 license.

Comment: The solution there would then be to create a CutomerLicense table, which could hold a one to many relationship (one Cutomer to many CutomerLicense)

Comment: ...And of course, you'd also have to modify the isLicenseValid function to handle multiple licenses (only handles one at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

You should keep a separate table for each license type:

```
LicenseID(PK)---Type

LicenseID(FK)---EndDate

LicenseID(FK)---TryTimes
```

and also maintain data integrity such as only time-trial licenses would come into the second table.

This will be also quite a scalable model, you will need to add one more table, one more integrity rule and one more interface in order to add another license type.

Comment: Tell you the truth, I'm not sure why, but I think this can limit the extensibility. I just don't feel right about this. But guess I have to think more. +1 for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single table as a parent and three other tables referencing the base table extending the schema.

That's the first option.

Another option is using a simple **NoSql** Database with low footprint or an **OO database** like db4o or even simple data stores like an **encrypted `XML` file**.